# How to execute shell script with arguments in remote unix server using robot framework from local windows machine

Tags: unix, ssh, robotframework

I would appreciate sample test steps to achieve this.

I logged into the server and then cd into the directory where the script resides. Then tried to run the script with Execute Command keyword.

Comment: Hello and welcome to [so]. Please review the [ask] section and amend your question accordingly. Moreover, consider providing a [mcve] of what you've tried so far.

Comment: The negative score on your question basically means urgent action is required. Please edit this question now and reply back when you are done.

Answer (score 0):

Install and import SSHLibrary, then use below code:

```
Keyword Name    
[Arguments]    ${server}=${host_url}    ${user}=${USERNAME}    ${pass}=${PASSWORD}
Open Connection   ${server}
Login    ${user}    ${pass}
${out}  ${err}  ${rc}=   Execute Command   cd ${SH_SCRIPT_PATH};sh ${SH_file_name}    return_stdout=True   return_stderr=True   return_rc=True
Should Be Equal   ${rc}  ${0}
Should Not Contain    ${out}    [main]ERROR
```